# How to compile a C++ program in LLVM using clang++?

Tags: c++, c, llvm, clang++

There is a tutorial - http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html Example done in pure C. I can compile and link it. Without problem, really. But I need C++, not pure C. And here the difficulties begin.

For clang++ I use string like

```
"C:\..> clang++ -c hello.cpp -emit-llvm -o hello.bc"
```

then:

```
"C:\..> llc -filetype=obj hello.bc"
```

and

```
"C:\..> link hello.obj -defaultlib:libcmt -out:hello.exe"
```

there I get 14 errors `LNK2001: unresolved external symbol`

So, I need some tips. What I do wrong?

```
//-----------------
```

hello.cpp:

```
#include < iostream >

int main()

{

    std::cout << "TEST\n" << std::endl;

    return 0;

}

//-----------------
```

OS: Windows7.

UPD: Main question: how from .bc get .exe? (LLVM, Windows7)

Comment: on my linux machine I can just run `clang++ -c hello.cpp -o hello`. that doesn't work on windows?

Comment: there is a way to get .exe, but I need to get .bc (bytecode LLVM), and then from .bc get .exe...

Comment: You don't post the link errors you are getting, but I guess it is the C++ runtime, this article indicates you need mcsvcr80.dll for C++ support, so I would guess you need to add that to the link line... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I have this dll, so there is not a point

Comment: first of errors I get: 
1)hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __ZSt4cout referenced in function _main
2)hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _strlen referenced if function __ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc                    14)last error: hello.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __ZNKSt9exception4whatEv

Comment: @kpdev I think you have to link to c++ library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use my [GCC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-dw2-4.6-release/) and [Clang](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/clang-3.1-release/) packages:

Download and extract them to the same directory. Clang will use GCC 4.6.3's libstdc++ and MinGW-w64's CRT. Call it like you would gcc.

Clang/LLVM cannot currently work with MSVC's C++ library, due to ABI issues. GCC's libstdc++ works quite well, though it has holes in surprising places (like `std::to_string`, `<regex>`, and `<thread>`).

Clang's Windows support is OK, but far from complete. You cannot for example dllexport whole C++ classes, unfortunately. And Win64 code generation is also not good enough to have a working C++ install (even in combination with GCC, like for 32-bit).

Comment: Looks like it works. Many thanks! But I've got new error: 
C:\Windows\System32>C:\Gms\mingw32-dw2\bin\clang++.exe -c C:\Alien\hellocpp.cpp -emit-llvm -o C:\Alien\hellocpp.bc
C:\Windows\System32>C:\Gms\mingw32-dw2\bin\llvm-dis.exe < C:\Alien\hellocpp.cpp | more
C:\Gms\mingw32-dw2\bin\llvm-dis.exe: Invalid bitcode signature                     (Why it appears?)

Comment: That I don't know. The point is that you don't have to go through LLVM bitcode anymore, but use Clang as a normal compiler and compile to object code and executables directly.

Comment: Don't have to go through LLVM bitcode anymore.... Too bad... My PhD research is developing compiler for academic programming language (lets name it APL). Now we have a translator from APL to C++. But my task is write a translator from APL to LLVM bitecode (at least, it would be nice). And, where possible, to use pre-written parts of APL->C++ translator.

Comment: Misunderstanding is quite possible because of my not perfect English, sorry. So, you do not know the cause of error "Invalid code signature"? Should I create a new question?

Comment: @kpdev I don't know the cause of that problem. I just tried doing `clang++ main.cpp -c -emit-llvm && llvm-dis main.bc && cat main.ll` and it works fine here with the above packages. `main.cpp` contained a C++ "Hello world!" program. Can you make sure nothing is weird on your end?

Comment: Where should I find cat.exe (for command `cat main.ll`)? In my computer only QtSDK have this file.

Comment: @kpdev `cat` is a Unix command that prints the contents of the file. You can find one for Windows [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html]. But just open the file in a text editor like [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or your IDE to check its contents.

Comment: Oh, I see, `cat` is for see the contents of the file. After `clang++ main.cpp -c -emit-llvm && llvm-dis main.bc` - I have main.bc and main.ll, and I can read main.ll - At first glance everything is normal, but then I doing `llc -filetype=obj main.bc` and then `link main.o -defaultlib:libcmt -out:main.exe` and here I get errors: `main.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
referenced in function ___cxx_global_var_init
main.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
referenced in function ___dtor__ZStL8__ioinit` and 12 errors more

Comment: At least problem solved! Instead of command `link hello.obj -defaultlib:libcmt -out:hello.exe` I done `g++ hello.o -o hello.exe` THANKS to all, and especially to rubenvb :)

Comment: Yes, you need to link with g++, cause clang currently does not work with the MSVC libraries. Glad I could help.